# Excel VBA How to find best price in worksheet and put all row to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi Excel and VBA Masters.

I have a problem and i'm sure You can help me :)

In this case:

I have a worksheet with some products, their prices and shops. I need to find every product with best price.

In Worksheet1 i have offers from shops:

[image]

In Worksheet2 i need to list all products **with their best price and shopname** (only rows with best price, without doubling)

[image]

I bet it is not hard to do it, but my excel skills are very shitty ( and i cant tell it to my boss ofc :) ) so i need a Help of stack community

Comment: Use a pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will tell you the product max for each product, populate in column D - use cntl+shift+enter to make it an array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,$B$2:$B$10))}
```

You can then use this to determine if the current row in the max, populate in column E:

```
=IF(D2=B2,1,0)
```

You can then use a pivot table and filter on columnE = 1

Answer (score 1):

Replace sheet1 & sheet2 with your source and destination sheets-

in sheets("Sheet1") & sheets("Sheet2")

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row).Sort Key1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3"), Order1:=xlDescending
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")    
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:C" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:C" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row).Sort Key1:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3"), Order1:=xlAscending
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```